# How to return the url of an image after uploading it to azure blob storage?

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I am new to using azure blob sotorage and am looking to return the storage url of an image after saving it to azure blob storage.

Example of my code:

```
  const uploadImage = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const blobName = getBlobName(req.file.originalname);
  const stream = getStream(req.file.buffer);
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  try {
    await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream,
      uploadOptions.bufferSize, uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
      { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "image/jpeg" } });
      res.send(httpStatus.OK, { message: 'File uploaded to Azure Blob storage.' });
    } catch (err) {
      throw new ApiError(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, { message: err.message });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. [`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest) has a property called [`url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#url) which is the URL of the blob. You can simply return that.

Something like the code below (untested though):

```
  const uploadImage = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const blobName = getBlobName(req.file.originalname);
  const stream = getStream(req.file.buffer);
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  try {
    await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream,
      uploadOptions.bufferSize, uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
      { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "image/jpeg" } });
      res.send(httpStatus.OK, { blobUrl: blockBlobClient.url, message: 'File uploaded to Azure Blob storage.' });
    } catch (err) {
      throw new ApiError(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, { message: err.message });
    }
});
```